# Find common element(s) in multiple arrays of strings in c++

Tags: c++

I have N arrays of strings,each of different size...what is the simplest way to find the common element(s) between them.

Example: Consider the following three arrays:

```
array1 = ("String1", "String2", "String3")
array2 = ("String3", "String2", "String5")
array3 = ("String2", "String3", "String5")
```

Expected output:

```
common_elements = ("String2", "String3")
```

`"String3"` and `"String2"` exist in all arrays so they are qualified to enter the output array. On the other hand, `"String5"` is only in `array2` and `array3`, and "String1" is only in `Array1`, and thus they both not qualify.

Comment: Whoever down vote a question please say why!! The guy doesn;t know why you down voted his question

Comment: What do you mean by 'common element' ? Please give us an example to work with.

Comment: Common strings which means for example 
if array1 has {"String1","String2","String3"}
and array2 has {"String3","String2","String5"}
and array 3 has {"String2","String3","String5"}
we observe that string3 and string 2 exist in all arrays so they are qualified to enter the output array...while String 5 which is only in array 2 and array3 is not.

Comment: Please update the question body to contain all details required to answer the question.  Comments are for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is

1. Sort all arrays. There is an overload of `operator<` which `std::sort` can use to place the elements in lexicographical order.
2. Pairwise apply `std::set_intersection`.

Example code:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1 {"hello","world"};
std::vector<std::string> v2 {"goodbye","world"};

std::sort(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1));
std::sort(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2));

std::vector<std::string> common_elements;
std::set_intersection(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)
                    , std::begin(v2), std::end(v2)
                    , std::back_inserter(common_elements));
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e51babf0b182dc49)

For more string-vectors, do that recursively. (There are more efficient solutions where you loop over all arrays at once, but this one is quick and standard-library-supported).

Comment: @Virtuoso If this answers your question than please mark this as correct